# Reading short from byte array

Tags: java, arrays, short

Looking for a solution to why my readShort function won't properly read this number (602).

byte array contains:
0x02 0x05 0x02 0x5A

```
byte tab = pkt.read(); //successfully reads 2
byte color = pkt.read(); //successfully reads 5
short len = pkt.readShort(); //problem
```

My readShort function, which has been working fine until this relatively large value came up.

```
public short readShort() {
    short read = (short)((getBytes()[0] << 8) + getBytes()[1] & 0xff);
    return read;
}
```

25A is 602, but it's printing that len = 90 (5A).  So why is it not reading the 0x02?

Sorry I ended up needing an extra set of parenthesis in my function.
Solution was: `short read = (short)(((getBytes()[0] & 0xff) << 8) + (getBytes()[1] & 0xff))`

Comment: This might or might not be it, but it could be the `getBytes()[0] << 8` line.  Try changing it to `(getBytes()[0] & 0xff) << 8`.

Comment: I tried that but it's still saying the length is 90.
Either way, I fixed it.  I needed another set of parenthesis.  New code is
short read = (short)(((getBytes()[0] & 0xff) << 8) + (getBytes()[1] & 0xff))

thanks though!

Comment: `(short)(((short)getBytes()[0]) << 8)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [`DataInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) and something like

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 0x02, 0x05, 0x02, 0x5A };
DataInputStream pkt = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
try {
    byte tab = pkt.readByte();
    byte color = pkt.readByte();
    short len = pkt.readShort();
    System.out.printf("tab=%d, color=%d, len=%d%n", tab, color, len);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output is (your expected)

```
tab=2, color=5, len=602
```